# How to group an array of associative arrays and declare custom keys?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, grouping

Can someone help me with converting a php array in a grouped format? I am trying to group them by `id`. I would like to have the following array converted:

```
$Arr1=Array
    (
        0 => Array
        (
            "id" => "4123",
            "test_number" => "1",
            "sat_total" => "1050"
        ),
        1 => Array
        (
            "id" => "4123",
            "test_number" => "2",
            "sat_total" => "1130"
        ),
        2 => Array
        (
            "id" => "4123",
            "test_number" => "3",
            "sat_total" => "1120"
        ),
        3 => Array
        (
            "id" => "5555",
            "test_number" => "1",
            "sat_total" => "1130"
        ),
        4 => Array
        (
            "id" => "5555",
            "test_number" => "2",
            "sat_total" => "1160"
        )
    );
```

into this:

```
$Arr2=Array
    (
        0 => Array
        (
            "id" => "4123",
            "Score1" => "1050",
            "Score2" => "1130",
            "Score3" => "1120"
        ),
        1 => Array
        (
            "id" => "5555",
            "Score1" => "1130",
            "Score2" => "1160"
        )
    );
```

I have tried a little bit, but can't seem to find how to make it work.

Comment: Doesn't seem massively complicated. What do you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to iterate your rows of data, determine if each row is the first occurring `id` value or not, then either declare the initial values, or add a variably keyed element to the group.  When the loop finishes, call `array_values()` to reindex the array (remove the temporary keys).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WHUW7))

```
$Arr1=[
    ["id" => "4123", "test_number" => "1", "sat_total" => "1050"],
    ["id" => "4123", "test_number" => "2", "sat_total" => "1130"],
    ["id" => "4123", "test_number" => "3", "sat_total" => "1120"],
    ["id" => "5555", "test_number" => "1", "sat_total" => "1130"],
    ["id" => "5555", "test_number" => "2", "sat_total" => "1160"]
];

foreach ($Arr1 as $set) {
    if (!isset($result[$set['id']])) {
        $result[$set['id']] = ['id' => $set['id'], 'Score1' => $set['sat_total']];
    } else {
        $result[$set['id']]['Score' . sizeof($result[$set['id']])] = $set['sat_total'];
    }
}

var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '4123',
    'Score1' => '1050',
    'Score2' => '1130',
    'Score3' => '1120',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5555',
    'Score1' => '1130',
    'Score2' => '1160',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this structure is ideal--it seems like your keys `"Score1"`, `"Score2"` etc would be best as an array like `scores => [1050, 1130, ...]` and it feels like the `id`s should be keys in the result array. But in any case, this gives your requested output:

```
$res = [];

foreach ($arr as $e) {
    if (!array_key_exists($e['id'], $res)) {
        $res[$e['id']] = [];
    }

    $res[$e['id']]["Score".(count($res[$e['id']])+1)] = $e['sat_total'];
}

$count = 0;

foreach ($res as $k => $v) {
    $res[$k]['id'] = $k;
    $res[$count++] = $res[$k];
    unset($res[$k]);
}

print_r($res);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Score1] => 1050
            [Score2] => 1130
            [Score3] => 1120
            [id] => 4123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Score1] => 1130
            [Score2] => 1160
            [id] => 5555
        )

)
```

Note that I did two passes which is a little verbose, but taking the time to key in the data ids into the array in the first pass should improve a linear search through the array for each element into *O(1)* hashing, so I think it's worth the extra loop block.

Answer (score 0):

This method will find the scores matching the $id.
It uses three array_intersects to match all the values correct.
This method will only loop the number of unique IDs, in your case two times.
Plus the times to create the score keys.

I do agree with what ggorlen says about the keys. That will also create a more efficient code.

```
$ids = array_column($Arr1, "id");
$sat = array_column($Arr1, "sat_total");

foreach(array_unique($ids) as $id){
    $new[$id] = ["id" => $id];
    $tmp = array_values(array_intersect_key($sat,array_intersect_key($Arr1, array_intersect($ids, [$id]))));
    for($i=1;$i<=count($tmp);$i++) $new[$id]["Score" . $i] = $tmp[$i-1];
}
var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/ag3To

The output is an associative array with id as key.
You can use array_values if you want to make it indexed.

---

Just to show how much more efficient the code can be with one score array.
This is what it would look like:

```
$ids = array_column($Arr1, "id");
$sat = array_column($Arr1, "sat_total");

foreach(array_unique($ids) as $id){
    $new[] = ["id" => $id, "scores" => array_values(array_intersect_key($sat,array_intersect_key($Arr1, array_intersect($ids, [$id]))))];
}
var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/mdA0W

Comment: `array_values` and `array_intersect_key` aren't efficient. These are all traversing the entire input array on every iteration, so this looks like *O(n^2)* if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Depends on how you want to read effecient. Three lines of code to transform an array is effecient code wise. Time effecient is a different matter. But in my opinion it's not that bad. Your code is faster, but not that much https://3v4l.org/NJoQk

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking, but try it on a larger test case--74 is too small to prove much of a difference between O(n) and O(n^2). Try this to randomly generate test cases >1000: https://repl.it/repls/FractalColorlessStructure. Here's the difference for only 5000 items: 0.6497859954834 vs.
3812.0427131653. That's a significant difference, and it gets much worse for larger data sets.

Comment: But you are effectively creating an array of unique IDs. Obviously that is not going to work on a code that is supposed to group items and loop unique IDs.

Comment: Do you understand the difference? @ggorlen

Comment: Respectfully, I have to agree, this is over-engineered and can be handled in a much simpler and easier to read snippet.  I've added my solution for comparison.

Comment: @mickmackusa overengineered true. But to call out a 3800 seconds loadtime is complete bs. If you are going to make a benchmark/comparison use a realistic set of data. Creating 5000~ish unique numbers is obviously not what OP has as he tries to group the array.

Comment: If I was an incoming developer looking at your code, I'd have to dedicate some brainpower toward deciphering your code logic.  I'm not going to downvote your answer, but I would never use it.

Comment: @Andreas Of course I do. Let's do 25000 entries (a medium dataset) with only 100 unique ids: 1.5574932098389 vs
522.30050563812. Sure, it's better than 5000, but I think the numbers speak for themselves here in disproving "but not that much". That's a whole order of exponential magnitude faster. Besides, who's to say the input won't contain 5000+ unique ids? OP has given no suggestion of uniqueness--it's totally feasible that you have a huge number of unique users with 1-2 SAT scores each. I can't understand the adamant defense of O(n^2) code when you have O(n) right there.

Comment: You do understand that I can say the same thing back to you? Who says 25000 is medium size? You obviously did not understand the difference, just admit it and let it go. If OP wants to group that is a clear indication that it's not n unique items.

Comment: The truth is, I picked 5000 entirely arbitrarily and as a low estimate, planning on running it on a "large" dataset of a half million or so entries, but your code wouldn't complete on anything over 5000, so I had to chop `n` way down and didn't adjust the uniqueness factor accordingly, which I happily did and your algorithm is still 500 times slower. See @mickmackusa answer for a good O(n) that's cleaner than mine. As for 250,000 being medium, it's all relative to the O size (for example, for a best-case O(n^2) algorithm, I'd call 5000 large). Call it what you want, I don't mind!

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr2 = [];
$i = 0;
$length = count($arr1);
do {
    $builder = $arr1[$i];
    // grab the first item from the original array

    $builder = [
        // set its initial properties
        'id' => $arr1[$i]['id'],
        'Score1' => $arr1[$i]['sat_total'],
    ];

    // initialise the subsequent score number
    $testNumber = 2;

    // prepare to look ahead in the original array for a matching id
    while (($i + 1) < $length) { // only look ahead if it is possible to
        if ($arr1[$i + 1]['id'] == $builder['id']) {
            // did you find a matching id? if so, let's set the subsequent score
            $builder["Score$testNumber"] = $arr1[$i + 1]['sat_total'];
            $testNumber++; // increase the next score number
            $i++; // increase the original array index
        } else {
            // no luck? let's go forwards and set the next record
            break;
        }
    }
    $arr2[] = $builder; // set the built record into the new array
    $i++; // move the pointer forwards
} while ($i < $length); // as long as there are items ahead
```

Not often you get to use a do-while. But it works :)

Feed it your original array `$arr1` and `$arr2` will be set.

It works by looking forward for matching `id`s. This solution assumes your original array is ordered by `id`! So unless you trust the input - don't use this solution!

Otherwise this is a simple, fast, and fairly readable solution to what looks to me like a school exercise?

If you want something that is safe, the other solutions here are suitable.